# Can't send shader to GPU memory

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader

I'm trying to link a glsl program with 2 shaders that have previously compiled succesfully, but the program won't link. According to glRemedy's debugger, the error message is `ERROR: Definition for "void main()" not found`. After some debugging, i found
out that the GPU is receiving NO shaders, again according to glRemedy. My code looks right
and performs as expected from client side, i believe.

Vertex shader:

```
layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexPosicao;

void main() {
    gl_Position.xyz = vertexPosicao;
    gl_Position.w = 1.0;
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
out vec3 cor;

void main() {
    cor = vec3(1, 0, 0);
}
```

Loading code:

```
bool Shader::fromCode(std::string strCode) {
    GLint result;
    GLchar *code = new GLchar[strCode.size() + 1];
    strcpy(code, strCode.c_str());

    glShaderSource(m_id, 1, const_cast<const GLchar **>(&code), NULL);
    glCompileShader(m_id);
    glGetShaderiv(m_id, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &result);
    return (bool)result;
}
```

EDIT:

After using `glShaderSource` on the shader ID i used, i got the source back. All of it. But it *seems* it's missing \n's. Would that be a problem?

EDIT 2:

Infolog says everything's ok. From the C++ code, the Program's Infolog says it's ok too, but from glRemedy, there's that error above. Also, i can't see the source of the shaders from glRemedy and their size is 0kb. And no, the test i have set up shows something's not working.

EDIT 3:

Merry Christmas! =D

Comment: Missing newlines are not a problem. GLSL treats them as whitespace, which can be reduced very much without hurting the parsing process.

Comment: Have you tried reading the shader info log using `glGetShaderInfoLog`?

Answer (score 1):

Why so complicated, that copy to a newly allocated GLchar* I mean (which you forget to delete[] afterwards). I'd rewrite it as

```
bool Shader::fromCode(std::string strCode) {
    GLint result;
    GLuint source_length = strCode.length();
    GLchar const * strCodePtr = strCode.c_str();

    glShaderSource(m_id, 1, &strCodePtr, &source_length);
    glCompileShader(m_id);
    glGetShaderiv(m_id, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &result);
    return (bool)result;
}
```

the additional source_length parameter takes care of any trailing garbage that might be found in the memory afterwards (number 1 reason, most people's shader loaders don't work).

Comment: I still can't send the shader.

Comment: @wingleader: I just noticed something? Where do you allocate the shader IDs? glCreateShader must be called somewhere to obtain `m_id`. If this happens in the constructur (i.e. Shader::Shader) it may happen, that there's no valid OpenGL context when the constructor is called. It makes sense to create the shader ID right before calling glShaderSource to avoid this problem.

Comment: `glIsShader` tells me it's a valid shader ID.

Comment: @BenVoigt `glShaderSource(m_id, 1, const_cast<const GLchar **>(&code), &size);`

Comment: @wingleader: I hate `const_cast` with a passion.  As you gain experience, you will too.  Just make `code` the right type and then you won't need it.  And in datenwolf's answer here, `strCodePtr` needs to be `const`, because the return from `c_str()` is.

Comment: @BenVoigt Ok, i changed that, but nothing is different at all on the results ( as expected ).

Comment: @BenVoigt: Yes, sorry, I missed that. Fixed